# Pathfinding sprite disappears when approaching the player in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, path-finding

I'm trying to make AI for enemies in my game. I applied a pathfinding (A*) script to my enemy sprite, after which the sprite began to follow the player. But when the enemy approaches the player, the enemy gradually disappears. This only happens in the Game section but in the Stage section the enemy does not disappear. And when the enemy is to the left of the player, he disappears altogether. How can this be fixed?

[image]

[image]

Here are the player settings:
[image]

Here are the enemy settings:
[image]

Here are the AIPath settings:
[image]

Here is the enemy script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Pathfinding;

public class EnemyGFX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AIPath aiPath;

    void Update()
    {
        if (aiPath.desiredVelocity.x >= 0.01f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);
        } else if (aiPath.desiredVelocity.x <= -0.01f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem a problem related to the pathfinding if you ask me. I recommend checking other things in your scene

Comment: Maybe you should raise the enemy's [SortingLayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SortingLayer.html) so that it always renders  top of the background.

Comment: To find out if it is a problem of your pathfinder, just deactivate it in the script and move both your player and the enemy at the position in the editor that causes the problem. It looks rather like the player has a huge transparent background that is erasing the sprite of your enemy

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem is with the player.  But I don't know how to remove this background.

Comment: Walk us through the steps required to reproduce a player object that exhibits this problem.